# Updating joomla admin component from 2.5 to 3.x

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I'm trying to update our templates and current modules and backend admin components to work with Joomla 3.

I've updated the component file to use `JControllerLegacy` etc where needed, and I can see it in my backend - basically. It's a field you put a string of information in, and that gets saved to the database and then gets re-used in other modules.

**I can input stuff into the text field, but if I go to click save, save and close, or cancel absolutely nothing happens.**

I haven't missed any files out as this was a direct import from a working version on 2.5.x and when I run web console it tells me:

`TypeError: b is null @ /media/system/js/core.js:4`

and

`Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ /media/jui/js/jquery.min.js:2`

Which I assumed was that it was trying to tell me the text field was empty.  However, no matter what's in there, it still doesn't do anything, and I would have thought the cancel wouldn't matter if there was anything in the box or not.

Any pointers would be great.

Comment: what's with the "joomla 3 shouldn't be used for public" attitude? it's stable, officially recommended for starting the new projects, and in a few days 3.1 version will come out, also recommended for public use for new sites

Comment: I said that because everywhere I read when someone posts a question about converting 2.5.x to 3 the first thing people say to them in that it shouldnt be used on public sites so to elimiate replies of such nature I thought I would put that in. We cant use them for public sites at the moment anyway as we are a business and need to make sure our templates are 100% working before we transfer them to the new 3.x hence why im starting to convert the stuff now.

Comment: Joomla! 3.0 is quite stable, by the end of the month will come out 3.1 which will be a one click update. Consider for new projects the 3 series as it will get new features and all the development will be focused on this series. The 2.5.x series will only get bug fixes and updates.

Comment: We would never release something that was not stable. Whether extension developers and templaters are ready is a different question.

Are you using jform for your field?

Comment: As previously said, Im not saying its unstable, I need to convert our current templates and extentions that we have built to work with 3.x first and text them to make sure they work first which is what Im doing now. Ive havent done a lot with the extentions/componants etc before and everything I googled says not to use 3.x yet but Im sure once I get it all working we will start our new customers sites based on the new one.

Answer (score 3):

Do you have the hidden inputfield `<input type="hidden" name="task" value="" />` in your form?

When clicking a button, the Javascript function `Joomla.submitbutton(task)` is called. This should be defined/overriden in your layout to make some checks and then call `Joomla.submitform(task)`, which fills the task into the hidden field and sends the form.

I think these functions have changed their name someday. Maybe you still got them without the `Joomla` prefix?

Comment: I'm very new to this and I didnt write the original extention just to clarify. Would it be better if I list the folders that in the com_NAMEOFFILE or someone point me to which file would be useful to paste the code from so I can be helped further the form page appears to have the hidden field in it, however I cant see any form of submit but it must have woked before because this is a direct copy from the joomla 2.5.9 copy with the added legacy to the end of the relevant files. Im sure its a name change or something similar in the new joomla thats causing it but Im not sure on which bit!

Comment: You can have a look at the sourcecode of the form and search for `submitbutton`. See if there is a Javascript function defined named `Joomla.submitbutton`. You can compare it with the form of an article.
Also search for the hidden field, using the keyword `task` you should find it fast.
Another thing is that the form has to be named _adminForm_ with an id of _adminForm_ according to http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1#JavaScript. Maybe check that as well.

Comment: Thank You!!! Your a star - it was the id="adminForm".

Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page - http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3.0_and_Joomla_Platform_12.1

Some things have changed between 2.5 and 3.0, mostly dealing with dropping 1.5 style code.  Also, take a look at the core components and use them as references to verify what you're doing is right.

Comment: Ive already looked at this page and added the new references where I can see the differences. Im Sure this is what is causing the issue but Ive gone through everything several times and I cant see where.

Answer (score 0):

the `JToolBarHelper:save();` was replaced with JToolBarHelper::save2new(); in further Joomla3 Versions